# A given folder (like C:\Random Folder), how can I find ALL the extensions and print them C#?

Tags: c#, file, directory

I've searched and found only how to get a certain extension(like txt.). I need to get all of the extensions and print them on the console. How is that possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Random\");
var allExtensions = dir.EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Extension).Distinct();
foreach (string ext in allExtensions)
    Console.WriteLine(ext);
```

Use this if you want to list all extensions also in sub-directories:

```
var allExtensions = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => f.Extension)
    .Distinct();
```